# How to use ZendSearch in Zendframework 2 with autoloader without zend application

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-search-lucene

I'm using Zend Framework 2 in a project with that code:

```
require_once APPPATH . "third_party/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php";

 $loader = new StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
 $loader->register();
```

How can I add ZendSearch from this github repo: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch

I dont know how to copy it into the zend directory, so that the autoloader finds it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ladys and gentlemen, here is the solution:

```
$loader = new StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->registerNamespace('ZendPdf', APPPATH . "third_party/ZendPdf");
$loader->registerNamespace('ZendSearch', APPPATH . "third_party/ZendSearch");
$loader->register();
```

Life could be so easy ;)